# how to call python function using jquery?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jquery

i am learning python with GAE and for interface use jquery so i want to know calling python function using jquery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery runs in the browser, operates on the DOM tree and gets data from servers mostly through asynchronous HTTP requests. Python runs on the *backend* - in case of GAE on Google's infrastructure. So the way to call functions on the server from the client is by making requests.

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

All you need for this to work is something on the server responding to a GET request to `ajax/test.html` - be it a static file or a Python function (e.g. a [RequestHandler)](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requesthandlers.html), which handles the request and returns some data.

Answer (score 1):

Use AJAX!!

Define a webapp page using

```
class AjaxPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        result = your_function()
        self.response.out.write(str(result))
```

And call it through the page's url through ajax.

Answer (score -3):

I believe you need to create a route for the app engine, and call that route with jQuery.

--EDIT-- The below turns out to be really really untrue, so don't mind it!!! I'm not going to remove it 'cause that would be lame. I have done some work with the Python SDK and tiny bit with the Java SDK, and doing so I felt the Python SDK was falling behind. More experienced programmers seem to disagree, hence this edit.

<strike>Have to warn you though, Google is focussing more on the Java platform than the Python platform; very often extra work is involved to achieve the same results as with Java, and sometimes things are simply unsupported.</strike>

What is your focus here? To learn Python or to learn Python with GAE?

Comment: Even if this alleged focus on Java rather than Python were true, what does that have to do with calling a route via Ajax, which is what you correctly state the OP needs to do?

Comment: main focus on Python with GAE.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, absolutely nothing. I just experienced it to be annoying to work with the GAE via Python because I often ran into trouble that you wouldn't have with Java thanks to the broader support, and I thought that that it might be good for someone who is getting started with it to know that...

Comment: Considering that version 1.4.1.0 was just released and created *yet another* need for Java people to sometimes use the Python SDK to do stuff that's not available in the Java SDK (migrating data from one app to another), I think it's kind of ridiculous to claim Google's concentrating on Java over Python.

Comment: I did not know that. I don't do Java, I do Python, but working with the SDK and GAE I just felt really hold back and ran into features that weren't supported for the Python SDK and were for Java. Stop ruining my already so sad reputation:p Just trying to help...

Comment: I did not know that. I don't do Java, I do Python, but working with the SDK and GAE I just felt really hold back and ran into features that weren't supported for the Python SDK and were for Java. Stop ruining my already so sad reputation:p Just trying to help...